# Scrapy freeze on connection timeout

Tags: python, timeout, web-crawler, scrapy, twisted

I wrote a scrapy crawler that uses an Internet connection that is pretty unreliable. This is something that is a given. I cannot easily or cheaply change it - once in a while the Internet connection will be lost and after a few seconds or so it will be restored.

I observe behaviour where a Scrapy 18.4 crawler would freeze indefinitely without printing any error messages. It stops reacting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which makes me think this happens somewhere pretty deep in the reactor stack, though I cannot be sure.

There are absolutely no error messages which makes things rather hopeless to debug.

**Question**: Would anyone have any clues as to how to debug this problem? I don't really have any meaningful logs to attach for the reasons laid out above.

Comment: Hmm, okay, after trying some random things, it seems I perhaps managed to resolve the issue by upgrading to Twisted 13.2 from 12.x. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Correction: Nope, that's not it.

Comment: If possible then share the code that you use

Comment: I think you don't need a code because it happens with any spider. This is some core issue in the networking stack.

Comment: Have you tried using a timeout in your requests ?

Comment: Hey, OP here, so for me this has been 1.5 forever ago. Not sure @patriotyk is experiencing the same "symptoms" as I was back then. For me, if I recall correctly the spider would get stuck somewhere deep in the call tree. And it would get stuck seemingly in some native code which then would prevent it from getting properly interrupted. So constructs such as `with` or any Python callbacks had no chance of helping this case since the thread would basically never be able to return to the Python land. As I indicated it wouldn't react to Ctrl+C or any "soft" signals.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a class for timeout and then run your code in a `try except`. Something like this:

```
import signal

class timeout:
    def __init__(self, seconds=1, error_message='Timeout'):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.error_message = error_message
    def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError(self.error_message)
    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.seconds)
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.alarm(0)

def run_crawl():
    while True:
        print("This runs")

try:
    with timeout(seconds=3):
        run_crawl()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Note: Since this uses `signal` it will only work on UNIX-based systems.

[image]

If you want it to go back to running the crawler (auto-restart), then you can just put it all in an infinite loop.

```
while True:
    print("Restarting spider")
    try:
        with timeout(seconds=3):
            run_crawl()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is all assuming that you can just keep restarting the bot after `x` seconds without major negative results. IE if you are constantly scraping the same page(s) over and over again, then this would work pretty seamlessly.

However, if you are scraping a very long list [once] and just want it to finish without an error, then it would work less well, but could still be used by setting `x` to a number that represents an amount of time greater than the duration of the entire process when it executes successfully (this is true no matter the length of the execution of the program - don't set `x` to 3 seconds if you are scraping one site that takes 7 seconds to complete, and the same is true if you are doing 5 that take 30 seconds or 500 that take 5 minutes, you will need to set `x` to an amount greater than that duration.

The reason that I specifically separated your bot having a quick completion time vs. not is that if it fails during a loop with a timeout of 30 seconds then you lose, on average, 15 seconds if it fails, but if you have a 30 minute execution time then you would lose, on average, 15 minutes when it fails, and if your internet is going out every 15 minutes, on average, then you would have it failing a vast majority of the time and you'll need to look more into debugging the problem and actually solving it instead of working around it, as this "solution" should definitely be considered a workaround.